# A word for an intentional error or absurdity inserted to check whether audience read an entire passage

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a tendency to write long(ish) and detailed emails at work that I suspect the target audience don't bother to read sometimes, so occasionally I will insert something obviously silly just to see if anyone picks it up.  Is there a word for that?

I am also aware of the similar practice of inserting intentional errors in, for example, maps for the purpose of detecting copyright violations - I imagine that would share the applicable terminology?

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there's a specific term for a meaningless bit of computer code whose only purpose is to prove provenance.

Comment: As Trump would tell you, this is a "gotcha".

Comment: Steganography, watermarking

Comment: @Kisama benchmarking

Comment: This is standard practice in CogSci when doing public surveys. They ask you to read their questionnaire and answer multiple-choice questions 1-7; then question 8 is something like "*If a quarter is worth 25 cents, how much is a quarter worth*?", to filter out people who are just answering blindly, without really thinking about the questions. It's useful to demonstrate your survey methodology was sound and the data collected are trustworthy. I bet there's a specific technical term for the practice in the discipline, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Gerald M. Weinberg uses the term **"bebugging"** for inserting flawed computer code to determine if the testing process is adequate, or if programmers have done a thorough code review (they find the intentional flaws).

Comment: Cromulence should work.

Comment: Am I the only one who triple read this question to make sure the OP wasn't doing this to *us*?

Comment: Audit review? (Joking)

Comment: *Carefully checks question for examples of this.*

Comment: Not going to submit this as an answer because it's a sidetrack, but related: an intentional error on a map is called a "cartographer's gremlin."

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Haha!  I am now consumed by regret at an opportunity forever lost...

Comment: "Is there a word for that?" - yes, it's called "being unprofessional".

Comment: @DanBron How do you tell from the answer to that question whether people are paying attention or not? Don't both people who are paying attention and people who aren't answer '25 cents'?

Comment: @jwg No, the people these sorts of questions filter out aren't reading the questions *at all*. They're just blindly marking "answer c" or whatever to get through the survey and get out of there. Apparently that problem was prevalent enough in psych studies to require this kind of control mechanism.

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to write shorter emails. ;)

Comment: I suggest you ask the people at The Workplace SE whether it is good practice to write long and detailed e-mails in which you embed traps to catch the inattentive.

Answer (score 39):

From Wikipedia...

> [**fictitious entry**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_entry)
>   *Fictitious or fake entries are deliberately incorrect entries in reference works such as dictionaries, encyclopedias, maps, and directories. There are more specific terms for particular kinds of fictitious entry, such as **Mountweazel, trap street, paper street, paper town, phantom settlement, phantom island, ghost word** and **nihilartikel**.*

From Dictionary.com...

> [**mountweazel**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mountweazel)
>   *Any invented word or name inserted in a reference work by a publisher for the purpose of detecting plagiarism.*
>   From *Lillian Virginia Mountweazel*, fabricated for the 1975 New Columbia Encyclopedia.

From Wiktionary...

> [**nihilartikel**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nihilartikel)
>   *A deliberately fictitious entry in an encyclopedia or academic work, generally identifiable as false, usually included to brand the intellectual property so copies can be identified.*
>   Considered a loan word from German; Latin *nihil-* nothing and German *artikel* article; from a fictitious March 2004 English-language Wikipedia article, referencing a September 2003 article in the German-language Wikipedia now titled *Fingierter Lexikonartikel*.

The terms ***trap street, paper street, paper town, phantom settlement, phantom island*** are all relatively transparent references to fictitious items on maps/atlases/etc.

As you can see, ***Mountweazel*** and ***nihilartikel*** are relatively recent coinages. Personally, I call fictitious entries in dictionaries ***ghost words***. My favourite example being [**contrafibularities**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrafibularities). I'd been laughing at that Blackadder skit for years before I realised it was actually a "mock Latin" pun on leg-pulling (*fibula* = a bone in the lower leg).

Comment: Have +1 and a badge for *contrafibularity*.

Comment: I like how some of your examples show that those invented words can gain a life beyond their intended purpose.

Comment: I think "trap street" could easily be generalized to other non-street items, as suggested by @Kisama in the question. In my opinion, "trap sentence" would be recognizable and descriptive to anyone familiar with the term "trap street".

Comment: @recognizer: I knew the *phantom island* before I went to that Wikipedia page in my first link, but if I'd ever encountered the other cartographical terms I must have forgotten them. And I recall my English teacher gleefully telling us about [Webster's **dord**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dord) (erroneous transcription of **D or d** abbreviated **density**) back in the 60s - I've no idea if he actually called it a "ghost word", but he obviously didn't call it a "mountweazel". That was a "mistake" rather than a "deliberate trap" though.

Comment: ...anyway, I focused more on devices used to prove plagiarism in *dictionaries* here because I think in most other types of written material it's less necessary from the perspective of the original author. That's because there are practically *bound* to be whole sentences in any original work *which have never occurred previously or since in an unrelated work*.

Comment: Purely as a related concept, in (British) counterespionage the term "Barium meal" was sometimes used to refer to false information which was fed to a single person. If the information was later discovered in the possession of the Opposition, it was clear who had passed it on. The terminology was borrowed from radiology, since ingested barium shows up clearly on x-rays, and made the digestive tract easily visible.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: That's an interesting one (borne out by [numerous written references](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=espionage+%22Barium+meal%22+)). I was perfectly familiar with the *concept* in the espionage context, but I didn't know that particular term before.

Answer (score 21):

In the United States, such a nonsensical insertion might be referred to as a "brown M&M" clause. As [this article from Snopes.com](http://www.snopes.com/music/artists/vanhalen.asp) reports, the rock band Van Halen included a contract provision at performances that the band be supplied with a bowl of M&M candies (which normally come in a mixture of colors—red, blue, yellow, green, dark brown, and (formerly) tan—backstage, with all of the brown-coated individual candies removed.

The point of the red-herring provision, according to Snopes, was simply to serve as an easily verifiable test of whether the promoter/host at each venue had carefully examined its obligations under the contract and met them:

> The legendary "no brown M&Ms" contract clause was indeed real, but the purported motivation for it [to provide legal cover—owing to the promoter's being in breach of contract—for destructive backstage behavior that the band would otherwise be liable for] was not. The M&Ms provision was included in Van Halen's contracts not as an act of caprice, but because it served a practical purpose: to provide a simple way of determining whether the technical specifications of the contract had been thoroughly read and complied with.

Comment: The full snopes article is perhaps the most entertaining thing I've read this month. Also, excellent example. :)

Answer (score 4):

Where I work, we call these ["Easter Eggs"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=easter%20egg)

Definition: A secret, hidden inside a video game, DVD movie, or even one of Strong Bad's e-mails. Often, it's not needed to progress a story.

Example: Wow, Strong Bad's emails are not only funny, but the Easter eggs really make me pay attention.

Comment: I might call them "Halloween Eggs", to differentiate from the more pleasant surprises of "Easter Eggs".

Comment: No, this is not what Easter Egg means. Easter Eggs are not hidden for the purpose of catching people who don't pay attention.