# Best or technical term for the act of including a *purposeful gaff* in writing?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

Although I suspect there are applicable examples in literature and newsprint, the specific context here is the online practice of either including a dud, or excluding an obvious/needed example in a piece, whereby an online viewer is encouraged to make a comment on the bottom of the webpage.  The author is architecting engagement to drive website traffic.

For example:

- Purposefully not including *Citizen Kane* in a piece or list about the best movies of all time.
- Cheekily including a Dan Brown novel when discussing or listing the best books ever written.
- etc. (but not so obvious...)

Basically, it's a troll move.  A professional tactic of trolling viewership.  I'm positive this is a gimmick used, and may even be taught in modern journalism schools.

What is the *best term* to use, whereby the largest number of readers would know right off what I'm talking about?  (Or, perhaps an exacting *technical term*, even if they have to look it up.)

- Dissonance writing
- Purposeful gaffing
- Contrived bounding
- Poetic dis license
- Hooking the reader
- Call and response
- ?

> Note: an obscure cultural cross-reference is the Bugs Bunny cartoon where a bomb has been wired to detonate if a particular piano key is pressed.  Bugs tricks Yosemite Sam into participating in playing, in the same way that I'm talking about an author tricking readers into engaging.
>
> - “Booby Trap” - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUsJXwE73QU
> - “Piano Boom”

Comment: The word _baiting_ comes to mind, but I'm not sure if that's a recognized term for it. Then again, maybe [_clickbait_](http://theamericanreader.com/life-sentences-the-grammar-of-clickbait/) is a term that describes what you're looking for?

Comment: _Clickbait_ entices viewers to a website, or into the _funnel_ if selling something. _“Sticky”_ has become a technical term (seriously) to describe design aspects of a website such that viewers come back to the domain again and again. The OP term is a 3rd distinct thing related to writing technique, although without doubt emoting someone in that way may be an intentional systematic ploy of _stickiness._ In fact I believe that is exactly the case, and why I'm looking for the best handy term to be able to talk about it. (I can't call the author out on it if no one knows what I'm talking about.)

Comment: It sounds like a [honeytrap](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/honeytrap) : A stratagem in which irresistible bait is used to lure a victim.

Comment: I wonder if there is a well known inverted/negative version of _honeytrap_? ... like _"bittertrap”_ or something.  (I'm also reminded of Robert Pirsig’s memorable term _[monkey trap](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2014/nov/14/how-to-avoid-monkey-trap-oliver-burkeman)_.)

Comment: Wait.  Dan Brown's novels aren't among the best books ever written?  Uh, oh.

Comment: Wasn't the nearly identical question asked about 5 days ago?

Comment: There is no telling what kind of damage _Dan Brown_ has caused you, making you misremember things.  It's possible he _[got all up in your kitchen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297488/etymology-of-getting-into-someones-kitchen)_?  (currently at very bottom)

Comment: It's a trap! Or a ruse, trick, ploy, gambit?

Comment: Your examples use inconsistency or incongruency in an attempt to elicit action from the audience. You could call it 'deliberative/deliberate rhetorical inconsistency/incongruency'. Idiomatically, it's known and despised as a 'cheap shot' (generic term). And "architecting engagement to drive website traffic" is known as 'doublespeak' (generic term).

Comment: Very closely related to this older question: [A word for an intentional error or absurdity inserted to check whether audience read an entire passage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286452/a-word-for-an-intentional-error-or-absurdity-inserted-to-check-whether-audience)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Great reference, and read.  (I _so_ wanted “Mountweazel” to work in this case, but no.)

Comment: I use a similar device when dealing with know-it-alls who insist on getting the last word: deliberately omit a good idea so that they have a chance to think of it instead of forcing themselves to concoct a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about '*contrived ignorance*'.

'Contrived' - Ingeniously or artfully devised or planned (OED).